# Python: Allow precision for very small number?

Tags: python-2.7, precision

In Python, when x=27., Exp(-x*x) is ~10^-317. When x is >27., Exp[-x*x] becomes zero in Python. But I will have domain of x from 0, to 50 or even more. So how can I stop Python from rounding exponential to be zero after x>27? Is it even possible to do it?

Thank you,
--Raj

Answer (score 0):

To calculate *very large numbers* with *python* you can try to use the **gmpy2** package like this:

```
import numpy as np
from gmpy2 import mpz
n = 50
print pow(mpz(np.e),n*n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The native Python float type uses the standard C double as the underlying value. You've reached the limits of the IEEE 64-bit floating point type.

You will need to use a different data type. I maintain the [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) library which supports arbitrary-precision integer (`mpz`), rational (`mpq`), real (`mpfr`), and complex (`mpc`) types. The library is written in C and uses the GMP, MPFR, and MPC libraries.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> gmpy2.exp(-50*50)
mpfr('1.8356726691621567e-1086')
>>>
```

The [mpmath](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mpmath) library is another good choice.